# Main sequence executed for call to non-existent wso2 esb

Tags: wso2, sequence

I am getting main sequence executed for call to non-existent in WSO2 esb when calling my service http://10.16.69.102:8280/payfast/token from postman I have tried http://10.16.69.102:8280/payfast/token/ as well but didn't work. Can anyone please help.

Its post request and I am posting the request to URL (http://10.16.69.102:8280/payfast/token) with x-www.form.urlencoded body and sending three key values in it and getting error 404 Not Found, but the method I set on WSo2 is post with correct URL (/payfast/token)

Comment: Add the source code of the API.

Comment: <api xmlns="ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="PayFastToken" context="/payfast" hostname="localhost" port="8280"> <resource methods="POST" url-mapping="/token" inSequence="payfast"/> </api>

Comment: Are you using the correct http method POST when calling the API?

Comment: Yes i am using https method POST

I just want to hit https endpoint from my wso2 esb, can you please guide me on this or tell me the steps so that i can make my first wso2 api

Thanks & Regards
Fawad Ahmed

Answer (score 0):

If you create API in WSO2 ESB like below,

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="test" context="/tests">
   <resource methods="POST" url-mapping="/custom/path" faultSequence="fault">
   ...
   </resource>
</api>
```

your API url will be like:
http://localhost/tests/custom/path

It is concatenation od your *context* atribute in API and *url-mapping*.
Second possibility is not to declare method for POST, but I assume that is not that case.

Provide that parts of your API code for better context of issue.

Comment: Dear tmoaz


My Api code is 


<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="PayFastToken" context="/payfast" hostname="localhost" port="8280">
   <resource methods="POST" url-mapping="/token" inSequence="payfast"/>
</api>